# Link for "start bounty" never disappears even when answers are given

Tags: discussion, bounties

I would like to know,

why does the "start bounty" link not disappear even when a question has an accepted answer?

My suggestion is it should be automatically removed or does its existence has any other significance? Is it a bug or a feature?

I just wanted to satisfy my query. Hope I'm asking at right place.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['start a bounty' shows for accepted answer question ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58206/start-a-bounty-shows-for-accepted-answer-question)

Answer (score 2):

> why does the start bounty tag does not disappear even when a question has an accepted answer?

Why should it? You can start a bounty even if an answer has been accepted, so this wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: Especially sine *anyone* can start a bounty, which is a great way to avoid duplicates.